# how to solve the reweighted Poisson equation efficiently

Tags: linear-algebra, poissons-equation, sparse-matrices

Consider the following reweighted Poisson equation: given  $\operatorname{Q} $ and $g$,
$$
(\nabla \cdot  \operatorname{Q} \nabla ) f = g,
$$
where $\operatorname{Q} $ is a diagonal matrix with positive entries. Note that $\nabla \cdot  \nabla$ is the normal Laplace operator.

I am working on a discrete reweighted Poisson equation in high dimensions like 10000*10000. Since $\nabla \cdot  \operatorname{Q} \nabla $ is a sparse matrix, I can use sparse linear solvers(the fastest package I found is [scipy.spsolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve.html)) to solve it. But it's still not efficient enough. Regular FFT cannot be applied directly due to the existence of the reweighting matrix $\operatorname{Q}$.  I wonder if anyone knows a better way to solve it, possibly other adaptions of FFT or specific sparse linear solvers?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.